# putting power series in closed form

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I came upon this problem whilst doing some reading about complex analysis and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Put the following power series into closed form:

1)  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2z^n$

2)  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(n+2)n!}$

I worked out that (1) converges only when $mod(z)<1$ and (2) converges for all $z$, but I have no idea how to work out what functions they converge to. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which power series can you "put into closed form"?

Comment: I just don't understand what I need to do! there are some standard results like z^n converges to $(1-z)^-1$ but I'm confused about how to approach these problems

Comment: You might know some closed forms for $\sum\limits_nz^n$ and $\sum\limits_nz^n/n!$. This could allow you to deduce closed forms for, say, $\sum\limits_nnz^n$, $\sum\limits_nn(n-1)z^n$, and others... which you might then want to play with to answer your question.

Comment: I really can't see how I get to either of the second two using the first two

Comment: Hint: $$\left(z\frac{d}{dz}\right)^k \sum a_n z^n = \sum n^k a_n z^n
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\frac{1}{z^k}\int_0^z \left( \sum a_n y^n \right) y^{k-1} dy = \sum \frac{a_n}{n+k} z^n$$

Comment: You do not know how to go from $\sum\limits_nz^n$ to $\sum\limits_nnz^n$, is this what you are saying?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** : $n^2 z^n = \left(n (n-1) z^{n-2}\right) z^2 + \left(n z^{n-1}\right) z$. Does this help you ?